# If every weak * convergent seq. is mapped to a strongly convergent seq. by $M^{'}$ , then $M$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Im stuck on the following exersice;

Given a bounded linear map $M: X\rightarrow Y $ where $Y^{'}$ is separable, show that $M$ is compact iff $\ell_{n} \in Y^{'}$ which is weak* convergent is mapped to $M^{'}\ell_{n}$ which is norm-convergent in $X^{'}$.

Hints regarding getting implication to $M$ is compact (i.e $ \Leftarrow$)  would be appreciated! I managed to show the implication assuming compactness.

Own approach:
I think I have shown this is true in reflexive spaces, but I don't see anyway getting that the weak * would imply weak convergence. Hence deducing that the space is reflexive.

Comment: You wont regain reflexiveness. You have to take another route

Comment: @TheOscillator Så jävla ruttet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Schauder's theorem you have to show norm compactness of $M'$, i.e., that every sequence $M'(\phi_n)$ in the image of the unit ball $B_{Y'}$ has a convergent subsequence. This ball is weak* compact by Alaoglu. Moreover, the separability of $Y'$ implies separability of $Y$ which gives that the weak* topology on  $B_{Y'}$ is metrizable. Hence you get a weak* convergent subsequence of $\phi_n$ and thus a norm convergent subsequence of $M'(\phi_n)$.

Comment: We need metraziblity since seq. compat is not implied nor implies compatness? I think there is a "seperable version" of Banach Alaglou in my text book. Given that the predual i seperable, then the unit ball is weak* seq. compact, this could been used aswell I think, giving us that the ball $B_{Y^{'}}$ is weak* seq. compact and thus $M^{'} \phi_{n}$ have norm convegent subseq. Am I right?

Comment: You are indeed right.